# KVM virtualization for CentOS 7

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, kvm

I am having an absolute devil of a time with KVM.  It seems every HOWTO out there offers a different list of packages, and I've installed them all:

```
[me@tarantula ~]$ rpm -qa | egrep 'kvm|qemu|virt'
qemu-kvm-common-1.5.3-105.el7_2.3.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-driver-secret-1.2.17-13.el7_2.3.x86_64
virt-manager-common-1.2.1-8.el7.noarch
libvirt-daemon-driver-network-1.2.17-13.el7_2.3.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-kvm-1.2.17-13.el7_2.3.x86_64
libvirt-client-1.2.17-13.el7_2.3.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu-1.2.17-13.el7_2.3.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-driver-nodedev-1.2.17-13.el7_2.3.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-config-network-1.2.17-13.el7_2.3.x86_64
libvirt-gobject-0.1.9-1.el7.x86_64
virt-what-1.13-6.el7.x86_64
libvirt-python-1.2.17-2.el7.x86_64
qemu-system-x86-2.0.0-1.el7.6.x86_64
libgovirt-0.3.3-1.el7_2.1.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-1.2.17-13.el7_2.3.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-driver-nwfilter-1.2.17-13.el7_2.3.x86_64
libvirt-glib-0.1.9-1.el7.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-driver-lxc-1.2.17-13.el7_2.3.x86_64
virt-install-1.2.1-8.el7.noarch
qemu-img-1.5.3-105.el7_2.3.x86_64
qemu-guest-agent-2.3.0-4.el7.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-config-nwfilter-1.2.17-13.el7_2.3.x86_64
libvirt-1.2.17-13.el7_2.3.x86_64
virt-manager-1.2.1-8.el7.noarch
libvirt-daemon-1.2.17-13.el7_2.3.x86_64
libvirt-gconfig-0.1.9-1.el7.x86_64
qemu-common-2.0.0-1.el7.6.x86_64
qemu-kvm-1.5.3-105.el7_2.3.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-driver-interface-1.2.17-13.el7_2.3.x86_64
ipxe-roms-qemu-20130517-8.gitc4bce43.el7_2.1.noarch
```

However:

```
[me@tarantula ~]$ lsmod | grep kvm
[me@tarantula ~]$ sudo modprobe kvm-intel.ko
[me@tarantula ~]$ lsmod | grep kvm
```

Nothing shows up in the logs or output of dmesg.  My CPU is a Xeon E5520 2.27GHz and does have 'vmx' in the flags.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, my installed kernel (3.10.0-327.10.0) did not match my modules.  Removing and reinstalling did not fix.  I had to remove the latest kernel, download 3.10.0-327 and install it, and all is well now.  Absolutely no idea why...